# WebJob publish from VisualStudio automatically inserting connection strings

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, publish, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I am trying to publish a WebJob from Visual Studio manually ("Publish as Azure WebJob"). This project references other projects that between them have 3 database connection strings. When VisualStudio starts to publish, it automatically adds the three connection strings from the referenced projects.

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069.aspx) explains that this in normal.

> Avoid editing database-related settings in the .pubxml file, because
>   Visual Studio changes these automatically as it finds changes in the
>   project

I want to stop this behaviour as I define the connection strings to use in the App.config

How do I stop the publish profile including the connection strings automatically?

Comment: You can override webjob app parameters from the config area of the website on the azure portal. The WebSite and the the webjob can share the same config.

Comment: I know. But I would like to automate the publishing. Ideally from the Build but as second best, from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager)
2. Move your connection strings to the appSetting section (for debug purpose)
3. Retrieve you connection string using the `CloudConfigurationManager`:

   ```
   var myConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyConnectionString");
   ```
4. Your connection strings won't be updated anymore when you deploy your webjob.